# Click listener on parent li also registers a click on child ul li submenu

Tags: angular

When I click on my services it opens up the submenu Email. But if I click on the submenu it toggles the menu from open to close while taking me to the correct link.
What should happen is the menu should only toggle when the parent li is clicked
 <

```
ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
    <li #myLi class="treeview" *ngIf="emailServiceUserExists" (click)="myLi.classList.toggle('active'); myLi.classList.toggle('menu-open') ">
            <a style="cursor: pointer;">
                  <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> <span>My Services</span>
                  <span class="pull-right-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                  </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li><a routerLink="/dashboard/my-services/email"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Email </a></li>
           </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: May be worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing Your inner `li` is essentially wrapped in an element with a click listener so any children clicked within the parent `li` will trigger the parents click handler. *"What should happen is the menu should only toggle when the parent li is clicked"* - the parent is being `clicked` every time.

Comment: thanks it worked `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"`

Comment: No problem, personally i'd look at taking the `.treeview-menu` `ul` out on it's own. this would most likely break your styles but may be a better pattern to follow in future.